# Xdebug stopped running after updating PhpStorm

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, local, xdebug

I was using PhpStorm version `2022.1.3` with [Local WP](https://localwp.com/) version `6.4.2` as a development environment. Local WP has an [extension](https://localwp.com/help-docs/advanced/using-xdebug-within-local/) to run Xdebug with PhpStorm. And all of that is running on macOS version `12.5` and Apple Silicon processor.

Everything was working seamlessly until I upgraded PhpStorm to version `2022.2`, the link between PhpStorm and Xdebug became broken and I was unable to stop running the code at any breakpoint.

I tried so many things to fix the issue that I can't even remember, I upgraded the Xdebug version to `3.1.5` but I have no idea what version I had before. I reverted PhpStorm back to version `2022.1.3`, I went throw tens of search results and support forums and tried every solution I thought it may help, but with no luck.

Comment: Enable Xdebug log is your first step -- it will tell if it tries to connect (and where), what the response is etc. Also check your live Xdebug config with `xdebug_info();`. I also suggest you try to debug a very simple script first, something like `<?php $a = 1; $b =3; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` where each command is on a separate line. This allows to ensure that basic debugging is working and then move to a more complex setup/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the following [bug with PhpStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67891/Step-Over-broken-for-Xdebug-30-for-static-methods-and-private-properties-from-parent-classes#focus=Comments-27-6367485.0-0), for which they've just released [a preview fix release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/08/phpstorm-2022-2-1-preview/).

Comment: OP says *"I upgraded the Xdebug version to 3.1.5"*, *"I reverted PhpStorm back to version 2022.1.3"*, *"...but with no luck"*. For me it sounds like he's still having an issue, even after downgrading the IDE and/or upgrading to the latest Xdebug v3.1.x

Comment: I installed the preview version, but it didn't work. I think I made many changes while trying to resolve the issue that may break the setup. I will keep trying. Many thanks!